# How to show only top edge of my bar graph in Matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a bar graph that only shows me upper contour and that within the bars is shown in white. I attach an image of what I want to obtain and what I have now.

```
photons=pd.read_csv("Average_weights_photons.txt", header=0, delim_whitespace=True)
xp=photons.R
yp=photons.total_weight

width=100
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
ax.bar(xp,yp, width, alpha=0.4, color="black", align="center", edgecolor='none')
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.set_ylabel("Number of particles")
ax.set_xlabel("Distance of the shower axis (m)")
ax.set_xlim(0, 4000)
plt.show()
```

I have this now
[image: I have this now]

I want to obtain some like this.
[image: I want to obtain some like this.]

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is a [step graph](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html), and not a bar graph.

Replacing

```
ax.bar(xp,yp, width, alpha=0.4, color="black", align="center", edgecolor='none')
```

with

```
ax.step(xp,yp, 'k',where="mid",linewidth=1)
```

should help. But, I am unable to verify since I do not have the dataset you have, but this seems to be working with an example set I generated. You can find my example below:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
yp=[random.randrange(i-4,i+4) for i in range(0,40)]
xp=[400-i for i in range(0,400,10)]
width=100
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
ax.step(xp,yp, 'k',where="mid",linewidth=1)
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.set_ylabel("Number of particles")
ax.set_xlabel("Distance of the shower axis (m)")
ax.set_xlim(0, 400)
plt.show()
```

I am attaching the example plot below.
[image: Step graph example]